# Изменить тип чата через Telegram Client API

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

Есть ли метод в Telegram Client API, который может изменить тип чата (с публичного на приватный)? Есть ли этот метод в telethon или pyrogram? Если да, то какой.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было изменить юзернейм на пустую строчку. Вот, например через такой метод в Pyrogram: https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/update_chat_username